# Boltzmann distribution and the most probable configuration

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

According to boltzmann distribution, 
$$\frac{N_i}{ N_j}=e^{-\beta(\epsilon_i - \epsilon_j)}$$

Where $N_x$ is number of particles in the $x^{th}$ state in the most probable configuration. $\epsilon$ is energy of that state and $\beta$ is temperature dependent constant.

So, from this we can infer that a higher energy state will always have lesser number of particles than a lower one in the most probable configuration, right?

(For convenience, let us assume that every energy level has only one state.)

My issue is, couple small examples I take seem to violate this principle.

For instance, take the case where you have 5 particles with total energy $5\epsilon$in a system with energy levels $0,\epsilon, 2\epsilon...$. You chalk out a table to find weights of all possible configuration.
[image]

Image from Atkins solutions

Now, the most probable configurations are {2,2,0,1,0...} and {2,1,2,0,0...}. But both of these cannot be the most probable configuration if Boltzmann's law is true.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the Boltzmann distribution describes the entire ensemble, not specific microstates.

Secondly, the Boltzmann distribution is irrelevant here. The microstates that are listed in your book belong to the *microcanonical* ensemble, which the Boltzmann distribution does not apply to (it applies to the *canonical* ensemble).

Answer (score 0):

The Boltzmann distribution only holds for really large N and macroscopic amounts of energy. You can't hope to have it work for just 5 particles and 5 quanta. The Boltzmann distribution assumes approximations that are actually very close to exact, but only if the number of particles of the system is uncountably large.